# RxJS operator for mapping elements of an array of arrays

Tags: typescript, rxjs

> disclaimer: I have a simple solution and want to document it here.

I've been looking through the RxJS [documentation for map methods](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api?query=map) that fit this requirement - let's call it `mapArray` - but have failed to find one.

```
of([1, 2, 3]).pipe(
    mapArray(num => num + num)
).subscribe(value => console.error(value));
```

I want an operator that will transform an Observable of one or more arrays (`Obserable<T[][]>`) and perform a mapping operation for each of the individual elements of each array.

Common use case for me is that I retrieve a list of elements from a server and wish to transform each json representation into their appropriate Typescript classes. This is a single item observable (just one array) but I would be interested in the general case (1 or more arrays).

```
let people$: Observable<Person> = of([{id: 1, name: 'joe', timestamp: '2019-10-11'}, {...}, ...]).pipe(
    mapArray(Person.fromJson)
);
```

I've come across this problem enough to warrant a custom operator for it. Anyone know a native RxJS operator for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution delegates to the appropriate rxjs pipe->map operator and then passes the function to the standard javascript map method on the array prototype:

```
function mapArray<T, R>(elementMapFunction: (T) => R): OperatorFunction<T[], R[]> {
  return function (oT: Observable<T[]>): Observable<R[]> {
    return oT.pipe(map(_array => _array.map(elementMapFunction)));
  }
}
```